# Crear variable agregada en SQL Query - PySpark

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

Soy bastante nuevo en SQL y estoy analizando los tweets contenidos en un fichero .json en el entorno de ApacheSpark. Tras haber leído el fichero, esta es su estructura:

```
tweets_sample.show()

+-------------------+----------+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                _id|created_at|lang|               place|    retweeted_status|                text|                user|
+-------------------+----------+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|1122569971345833984|1556476512| und|                null|[1122566927866634...|RT @Ibero_DMJ: ...|[2511, 4383, 1069...|
|1122570131736006656|1556476550|  pt|                null|                null|@CervantesFAQs @C...|[33, 119, 1030176...|
|1122570215445999617|1556476570|  es|                null|[1122561071426998...|RT @rtve: El PSOE...|[1741, 1498, 2503...|
|1122570274610851846|1556476584|  es|                null|                null|#SiguemeYTeSigoVo...|[71, 243, 1079050...|
|1122570283129479169|1556476586|  es|                null|[1122541491895832...|RT @Aljiuss: Ahí ...|[1, 31, 112249025...|
|1122570300904878080|1556476590|  es|[[[[[-5.274768, 3...|                null|Ejemplos de porqu...|[1130, 1029, 5550...|
|1122570301940871168|1556476590|  pt|                null|[1122300505810714...|RT @DCM_online: P...|[177, 372, 773690...|
|1122570422178938880|1556476619| und|                null|                null|    |[5808, 507, 13945...|
|1122570463962595334|1556476629|  es|                null|[1122570189760028...|RT @Oktubrenotici...|[99, 68, 10570472...|
|1122570610381660160|1556476664|  es|                null|[1122523272300548...|RT @_iMperfectB: ...|[543, 426, 155764...|
|1122570676009828353|1556476680|  es|                null|[1122078996819214...|RT @fer2365: El v...|[126, 289, 102323...|
|1122570782452985857|1556476705|  es|                null|[1122537396120240...|RT @roja_red: ¡Ca...|[182, 156, 940597...|
|1122570894013095937|1556476732|  es|                null|                null|Tampoco harán cas...|[420, 1613, 69989...|
|1122571003677245440|1556476758|  es|                null|[1122437856671281...|RT @rubitahmusic:...|[751, 712, 297657...|
|1122571041182748672|1556476767|  es|                null|[1122453843097288...|RT @malaumaral: V...|[71, 243, 1079050...|
|1122571056911405057|1556476770|  es|                null|                null|@mery_a_e ...pues...|[63, 148, 3253622...|
|1122571091925458945|1556476779|  es|                null|                null|#canarias no form...|[34, 105, 3793360...|
|1122571133658832898|1556476789|  ca|                null|[1122484603573428...|RT @MiriamSBrichs...|[903, 199, 974420...|
|1122571169167826945|1556476797|  es|                null|[1122548849376145...|RT @jonathanmarti...|[290, 346, 249219...|
|1122571285861736448|1556476825|  es|                null|[1122541491895832...|RT @Aljiuss: Ahí ...|[16, 117, 1048539...|
+-------------------+----------+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Más información sobre la estructura se puede obtener con `printSchema`:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- place: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bounding_box: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country_code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- place_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- statuses_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- statuses_count: long (nullable = true)
```

El caso es que quiero crear una tabla `users_agg` con la información agregada de los usuarios que tengan definido su idioma como español. Además, la tabla contendrá las siguientes columnas:

`screen_name`: nombre del usuario

`friends_count`: nombre máximo a las personas que sigue

`tweets`: nombre de tweets realizados

`followers_count`: nombre máximo de personas que siguen al usuario

Para obtener la table, he realizado la siguiente query:

```
users_agg = sqlContext.sql("SELECT user.screen_name, user.friends_count, user.followers_count FROM tweets_sample WHERE user.lang = 'es' ORDER BY user.friends_count DESC")

users_agg.limit(10).show()
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
|  screen_name|friends_count|followers_count|
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
|     MrPINTXO|       167865|         166591|
|      Zurine3|       106781|         102566|
|     caval100|        93692|         120142|
|     caval100|        93691|         120144|
|     caval100|        93690|         120168|
|     caval100|        93689|         120166|
|     caval100|        93669|         120161|
| CiudadanosCs|        92910|         511896|
|javierfagreda|        66362|          69349|
| Telegrafia01|        65558|          57593|
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Como podréis ver, la columna `tweets` que quiero no esta en la tabla. Mi problema es que no sé como puedo crear una variable si esta no esta contenida en la estructura de los datos. La variable `tweets` debería ser creada como la suma de tweets para un mismo usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas creo que te falta en *select* el campo de la salida

```
***COUNT(*) AS tweets*** 
users_agg = sqlContext.sql
("SELECT user.screen_name, 
         user.friends_count, 
         user.followers_count,
        ***COUNT(*) AS tweets*** 
FROM tweets_sample 
WHERE user.lang = 'es' 
ORDER BY user.friends_count DESC")
```

> **P.D.:** ¿Estas haciendo  Análisis de datos en entornos Big Data en UOC?.
> ¿Por qué pones delante user?
>
> Te lo he visto y lo he puesto y ahora no me falla